# Import requests results in error even after installing and uninstalling multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I am working in a virtual environment and I have installed and uninstalled `requests` multiple times, each time without any warnings or errors.

The weird part about my issue is that the `ModuleNotFoundError` is only thrown in certain places. When running my script (which imports `requests`), when I import the script, and when I import `requests` in the IDLE shell, I am given the error. (This is all done in the virtual environment - don't worry, I check multiple times!) However, when I run `python` from the command line and perform all of the above actions, I don't receive any errors.

## Installed Packages

```
$ pip list
Package        Version
-------------- ---------
beautifulsoup4 4.9.3
certifi        2020.12.5
chardet        4.0.0
idna           2.10
pip            20.3.3
requests       2.25.1
selenium       3.141.0
setuptools     49.2.1
soupsieve      2.1
urllib3        1.26.2
```

## Specs

- Python 3.8.6
- Windows 10 Home, 64-bit
- git version 2.29.2.windows.3

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using vscode. The reason is that you might setup the virtual environment in vscode but terminal is not recognizing the virtual environment. Thus whenever you install the module it will install globally not in a virtual environment. So hence when you directly run the code you get the error but since terminal is setup for using system Python path instead of virtual environment than path thus terminal run the file with no issue . If you had setup the virtual environment than make sure you had setup
correctly.
Before installing requests module activate virtual environment by
source venv/bin/activate
than install the requests module by
pip install requests

Comment: I’m not using VS Code. I’m just using Python IDLE. I’ve been too lazy to install an IDE.

Comment: it is better to install requests module from setting of your ide. You can also activate venv in your terminal by above source venv/bin/activate than install requests module. You can also install the requests by 
following the guide instead of installing directly from commandline https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: To check virtual environment is activated use "which python" it will show the current path of your shell.

Comment: I’ve already done all this stuff. I have been working in a virtual environment and I made sure it was activated when installing requests. I mentioned that in the original post.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot link.

Comment: Screenshot of what? The error message just says `ModuleNotFoundError`. I know the virtual environment is activated because it says `(virtualenv)` prior to each line.